# "The document path provided in the update expression is invalid for update" when trying to update a map value

Tags: python, amazon-dynamodb

Here is my sample code

```
import boto3

import os

ENV = "dev"
DB = "http://awsservice.com"
REGION = "us-east-1"
TABLE = "traffic-count"


def main():
    os.environ["AWS_PROFILE"] = ENV
    client = boto3.resource("dynamodb", endpoint_url=DB, region_name=REGION)

    kwargs = {'Key': {'id': 'D-D0000012345-P-1'}, 
            'UpdateExpression': 'ADD #count.#car  :delta \n            SET #parentKey = :parent_key, #objectKey = :object_key', 
            'ExpressionAttributeValues': {':delta': 1, ':parent_key': 'District-D0000012345', ':object_key': 'Street-1'}, 
            'ExpressionAttributeNames': {'#car': 'car', '#count': 'count', '#parentKey': 'parentKey', '#objectKey': 'objectKey'}}

    client.Table(TABLE).update_item(**kwargs)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

What I want to achieve is this:

With a single API call (in this `update_item`), I want to be able to

1. If the item does not exit. create an item with a map `count` and initialise it with `{'car': 1}` and set the fields `parent_key` and `object_key`.

or

2. If the item already exists, update the field to `{'car': 2}` (if the original count is 1)

Previously, if I did not use a map,  I can successfully update with this expression,

```
SET #count = if_not_exist(#count, :zero) +  :delta, 
    #parentKey = :parent_key, #objectKey = :object_key
```

However I am getting this error:

> botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred
> (ValidationException) when calling the UpdateItem operation: The
> document path provided in the update expression is invalid for update

Which document path  is causing the problem? How can I fix it?

Comment: I created an issue for the SDK to be able to upsert a nested key on update:
https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js-v3/issues/5239

Answer (score 13):

For those who landed on this page with similar error:

```
The document path provided in the update expression is invalid for update
```

The reason may be:

```
for the item on which the operation is being performed, 
this attribute (count, for example) is not yet set.
```

Considering the sample code from question,
The exception could be coming from all those items where `count` is empty or not set. So the update query doesn't know on which `map` the new value(s) (car, for example) needs to be set or updated.

In the question, it was possible for the OP in the beginning because, the attribute is not a `map` and the process is simply setting the value to `count` as is. It's not trying to access a key of an unknown map to set the value.

This can be handled by catching the exception. For example:

```
from botocore.exceptions import ClientError
...
try:
    response = table.update_item(
        Key={
            "pk": pk
        },
        UpdateExpression="set count.car = :c,
        ExpressionAttributeValues={
            ':c': "some car"
        },
        ReturnValues="UPDATED_NEW"
    )
except ClientError as e:
    if e.response['Error']['Code'] == 'ValidationException':
        response = table.update_item(
            Key={
                "pk": pk
            },
            UpdateExpression="set count = :count",
            ExpressionAttributeValues={
                ':count': {
                    ':c': "some car"
                }
            },
            ReturnValues="UPDATED_NEW"
        )
```

Comment: I believe this exposes a race condition if another update adds the `count` map in between the first and second updates. It would end up overwriting the values set by the other update.

Instead you might want to consider doing _two_ extra updates. One that creates `count` as empty (i.e. `{}`) only if it doesn't exist using the `if_not_exists` function. Then retry your original update as-is.